# How to buffer webservice data in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, authentication, buffer

I am logging in android app through web service and getting the app data after the login service but I want if app is not signed out and closed the next time I open the app it should be logged in and the login service should not call again. For this I have to store the previous service data in some buffer. What this buffer should be ?
I have no idea how to achieve this. Need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to store key,value data pairs:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

For more info, [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Are you saving the data in a string like R.string.saved_high_score ??

Comment: that's the key, the value is the int newHighScore

Comment: so we have to store all the service response in sharedprefrence in a key value pair and will read that if already logged in . Right ?

Comment: Right, this article explains it very well  you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check wither the login response has been saved recently or not in splash screen and in this screen you can redirect user to home if response has been saved of login or redirect to login screen if data has not been set recently. For that SharedPreferences is good way to store response in string format and you can parse in model or hashmap.